# Caching asp.net mvc views

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am looking to improve the performance of my asp.net mvc web application and came across the following article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/08/16/optimizing-mvc-view-lookup-performance.aspx

I notice the performance improvement this gives and was looking to implement it. However I know the article is some years old so wondering maybe this has already been introduced to the MVC framework. Can anyone confirm if this is the case? I will be running my application in release mode.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to improve the performance of?  The post you linked to specifically says: _"The results below are only relevant to DEBUG mode"_.  If view lookups are truly your performance problem then simply compile in release mode and make sure your `debug` attribute is set to false.

Comment: If you read full article you will see there is also an optimisation when in release mode with extra layer of caching.